# A question related to Limit on Improper integral

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits, improper-integrals, pointwise-convergence

Which ones will be correct and why?

If continuous functions ${f_n}$ converge to continuous function $f$ point wise on $\mathbb{R}$ .

$1)$$0 \leq f_n\leq f$ then $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f_n(x) = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f(x)$

$2)$ $|f_n(x)|\leq |\sin(x)|$ for all $x \in \mathbb{R}$ then $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f_n(x) = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f(x)$

$3)$ $|f_n(x)|\leq e^x $ for all $x \in \mathbb{R}$ and $a$ less than $b$  and $a,b \in \mathbb{R}$ then $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\int_{a}^{b} f_n(x) = \int_{
a}^{b}f(x)$

All I know Uniform convergence alone can not permit the limit to get into the integration. But How I would proceed for this case I have no idea. Can anyone help me out?

Comment: Do you know the dominated convergence theorem?

Comment: yes..So is my question from measure theory?@zhw.

Comment: I don't know where your questions are from. But when you say you have no idea, and yet you know the DCT, that doesn't compute. So try the DCT and get back to us.